# When I connct to a VPN I have a new ip for the internal network in my windows but NO in the linux subsystem (WSL)

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to use a WSL in my windows virtual machine. I have access to a vpn, and when I connect with Pulse secure everything works find for the windows comand line. I get "Ethernet Conexión de área local* 2" with a new ip corresponding to the range of the internal network. However, linux subsystem is NOT able to reach the network. There is not a new generated ip for the private network. I still having the eth0 I had before connect.

Comment: wait so you have some OS, and then Windows in a virtual machine, and then WSL (which as of WSL2 is *also* a virtual machine) inside that? Why don't you just run a linux VM *next to* the Windows one, so that way you don't get the massive performance dip from running nested VMs?

Comment: [why is there no network connectivity in ubuntu using wsl2 behind vpn](https://superuser.com/questions/1582623/why-is-there-no-network-connectivity-in-ubuntu-using-wsl-2-behind-vpn) [wsl2 dns is not working with vpn connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444822/wsl-2-dns-is-not-working-with-vpn-connection-on-win-10) [wsl2 vpn workaround instructions](https://gist.github.com/machuu/7663aa653828d81efbc2aaad6e3b1431)

Comment: Corporative staff is not something that depends of me. There is no need of connections inside the vpn, Actually the infra has not internet , I only need to be able to take part of the network  having the ip

Comment: the problem is that VPN + WSL2 *doesn't work* by default. These answers explain how to fix.